# How to display version of application publicly

Tags: php, git, azure, laravel, bitbucket

Usually we set the version of application with guideline of semantic versioning (http://semver.org/). While our application automatically hook by azure, deploy with bitbucket git. We will put the version into the git as well, but some time testers don't know when should they start to do the testing. They don't know whether the application is updated to version or not and don't know when the version deployed.

Is it possible to get the information either from git commit message, or last deployment from azure history into the footer of laravel application? How you do the versioning control, which detail up to patch level of updates. Please advice what keyword should i search with, while i tried but no luck. results are irrelevant.

Comment: `git describe` output will be good version-id

Comment: @LazyBadger, how can i get the output into the file or variable?

Comment: if Git exist on Azure instance `echo exec('git describe')`. If Git doesn't exist, include "<some file>" in Laravel templates, in which (git hook?) will output `git describe` - it's text string, oneliner

Comment: @LazyBadger, don't have git on azure i think. tested with terminal and result in no names found, cannot describe anything

Comment: Git Describe uses tags to do its work.  Most projects place tags in the repo to mark release versions.  Of course if you don't place those tags, describe won't work.

Comment: @tjd is there any other methods to do it? how you manage versioning?

Comment: Look up `git tag` & use them to label your releases...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display the active git tag with php without exec / shell\_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107313/how-do-you-display-the-active-git-tag-with-php-without-exec-shell-exec)