# How do you display the active git tag with php without exec / shell_exec

Tags: php, git

Assuming a tag is currently checked out, and the .git folder sits in the root of the site's codebase, I'd like to include the tag in the rendered html of a page using php.

I've seen solutions which make use of shell_exec / shell, but assuming I'm unable to use those two functions, how can I get the label of the currently checked out tag. For example `v1.2.3` using php alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED 04-01-2022** to trim contents to remove (trailing) whitespace.

You can get the current HEAD commit hash from `.git/HEAD`. You can then loop all tag refs to find a matching commit hash. We reverse the array first as you're more likely to be on a recent tag than an old one.

Obviously replacing the `exit`s with variables and spitting it to the page will give you a better result.

So if your php file sits in a `public_html` or `www` folder one level down from the `.git` folder...

```
<?php

$HEAD_hash = file_get_contents('../.git/refs/heads/master'); // or branch x

$files = glob('../.git/refs/tags/*');
foreach(array_reverse($files) as $file) {
    $contents = trim(file_get_contents($file));

    if($HEAD_hash === $contents)
    {
        exit('Current tag is ' . basename($file));
    }
}

exit('No matching tag');
```

Comment: I cannot get hash from HEAD because my `.git/HEAD` contains something like `ref: refs/heads/master`

Comment: Spot on. I've updated my answer to point to `../.git/refs/heads/master`

Comment: Sadly this no longer seems to work. None of my tags have the same hash as their corresponding head hash.

Comment: @VinceKronlein I've updated the code. It now functions as expected again. At some point the tags references started having trailing spaces added.